# BASE_URL setting for a proxied sites

Tags: uri, proxies

for a Drupal7 document root which is served though a reverse proxy such as http://www.example.com/info, then the site should have a $BASE_URL setting of http://www.example.com/info, and that should result correct loading of file assets.  Is that correct?

As a result, that site source would contain links like 
  http://www.example.com/info/sites/default/files/logo.png
and
  http://www.example.com/info/misc/jquery.js?v=1.4.4
and
  
and
  http://www.example.com/info/my_alias_to_node_333

Just wanting to clarify expected behavior, as we can (at the moment) only get to the proxy context in a production environment; in non-production environments, we hit the site directly at the document root, without the reverse proxy, and have a $base_url setting, accordingly.